# Angular textarea can't be filled with default value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, textarea

I'm trying to put a default value to my Angular textarea. I think I tried everything possible. Nothing worked. I have a html template

```
<textarea ng-model="title" required class="textbox" id="feedbackInput" ng-init="title= initvalue"></textarea>
```

which is connected to the component\controller:

```
angular
    .module('feedbackForm')
    .component('feedbackForm', {
        templateUrl: 'feedback-form/feedback-form.template.html',
        controller: ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Feedback', '$localStorage',
            function FeedbackFormController($scope, $routeParams, Feedback, $localStorage) {
                console.log('FeedbackForm Controller');
                var self = this;
                var feedback = "";
                $scope.initvalue = "hhhhhh";
            }
        ]
    });
```

It doesn't work. It doesn't fill my textarea. I tried using this, self, $ctrl... any ideas how to set a default value in my textarea without changing the controller too much.

Comment: Before putting some default value into your textarea, consider using the **placeholder** attribute to guide your users.
Otherwise, check the answers below.
And please read the documentation about [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) before using it everywhere.

Comment: I dont want a placeholdert. I want an actual editable text in the textarea

Comment: Can you give me a good reason why you choose this solution ?

Comment: I want a page where my users can add a feedback but if they already gave a feedback, I want them to be able to edit it instead of just write another. It's for an interview feedback

Comment: Here is a very small example of how to do it then :
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/9701/).

No need of ng-init. Just remove this attribute.
For the rest I think you can manage to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like This

```
<textarea ng-model="title" required class="textbox" id="feedbackInput" ng-init="title= 'initvalue'"></textarea>
```

or Try Like This in Controller

```
$scope.title='Default value'
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I tried both. the first one prints the string "initvalue" i nthe text area which is not what I want. The second one just doesn't ut anything in my textarea.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the default value to the textarea's ng-model in the respective controller or use ng-init.

Example (using ng-init):

```
<textarea ng-init='foo="Some default value"' ng-model='foo'></textarea>
```

OR (without using ng-init):

```
<textarea ng-init='foo="Some default value"'>{{foo}}</textarea>
```

Comment: DId you read my code? Cause that's what I tried. I set a ng-model and I also tried using ng-init. They just dont work though so I might be doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar using `material` UI in angular. This is what I did :

```
<form [formGroup]="demoFormGroup"> 
    <mat-form-field>
       <textarea matInput formControlName="eventBody" placeholder="Your Message" cdkTextareaAutosize cdkAutosizeMinRows="6"></textarea>
     </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

in `.ts` file, inside `ngOnInit`,

```
ngOnInit(): void{
   this.demoFormGroup= new FormGroup({
      ....
      ....
      eventBody: new FormControl("Demo Text", [Validators.required]), 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your textarea tag you can simply use an ng-value attribute which will then serve as a default value by creating a one-way data binding in addition to the two-way data binding:

```
<textarea ng-model="someModeledVar" ng-value="someDefaultVar"></textarea>
```

This won't work however unless you write it like this instead (I will explain why below):

```
<textarea ng-model="someObj.someModeledVar" ng-value="someObj.someDefaultVar"></textarea>
```

If you want pure two-way binding (which is the method I personally recommend), then use only ng-model without ng-value and give the var that ng-model models an initial value in your controller like
that:

```
// js
$scope.someModeledVar= 'this is my default string';
//Template
<textarea ng-model="someModeledVar"></textarea>
```

Notice however that if you assign it a primitive value like this, it can probably not work because of a common pitfall related to scope inheritance in angular js and you will be wondering why your ng-model is not being updated properly in your js controller.

To avoid this change your primitive value to be a property in an object like:

```
//js
$scope.data = {
  someModeledVar: 'this is my default string'
};

//Template
<textarea ng-model="data.someModeledVar"></textarea>
```

and it will save you a lot of pain and heartache wondering why ng-model is not working, regardless of which method of the above you choose.

Answer (score -3):

I think what you are looking for is [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_placeholder.asp)?

Comment: I dont want a placeholdert. I want an actual editable text in the textarea