# Adding Default Value To Text Input Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Background**

I have a form with an input field containing the user's email address. I am using interpolation to add the email to the `placeholder` field.

**Problem**

I do not want the user to be able to change the email address in this field. I only want them to be able to see it. But I do want it to post with the form.

**Question**

I keep trying different ways and no matter what the `form` does not `post` the email. How can I `bind` it so that it will actually `post` the email address when the form is `submitted`?

**Examples**

I tried with `readonly`. That way they would not be able to change it.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" [(ngModel)]="personal.email" name="email" #email="ngModel" placeholder="{{auth.user.email}}" value="{{auth.user.email}}" readonly>
```

I tried without `readonly` just to see if it would work if I do not add any restriction flags.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" [(ngModel)]="personal.email" name="email" #email="ngModel" placeholder="{{auth.user.email}}" value="{{auth.user.email}}">
```

I know the email is accessible because I am adding it to the placeholder field and it shows up in the form. It just wont post.

Comment: May be you can add one more html "hidden" control , with the same interpolation.. not sure if that meets your requirement.

Comment: Maybe of some help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593725/angular-textarea-cant-be-filled-with-default-value/76206452#76206452

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default value will be the value assigned to `personal.email`.

Alternatively you can bind to a different property

```
[(ngModel)]="personalEmail"
```

and assign a default value to `personalEmail` and on submit update `persona.email` in code or use

```
[ngModel]="personalEmail" (ngModelChange)="personal.email = $event"
```

to get the initial value from `personalEmail` and update `personal.email` when changes happen

This might also work (not tried)

```
[ngModel]="personal.email || 'defaultValue'" (ngModelChange)="personal.email = $event"
```

to only get `'defaultValue'` assigned if `personal.email` is `null`

Answer (score -1):

Here model is `personal.email` and the default value is `auth.user.email`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" [(ngModel)]="personal.email = auth.user.email" name="email" #email="ngModel">
```

Comment: "Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 8 in [personal.email = ''] "