# Add default value to input field Angular2

Tags: angular, input

I'm trying to build an angular 2 application, my problem is that i want to give a default value for an input and make it disabled i tried this but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="input01">UUID</label>
    <input class="form-control form-control-rounded" id="input01" style="width:600px;margin-left:60px" type="text" [(ngModel)]="beacon.uuid" value="{{uuid}}" name="uuid" disabled>
  </div>
```

Any solution?

Comment: try placeholder = {{uuid}}

Comment: If you don't want to store default value in your model check
[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40882301/3035471) aswer

Comment: you should be setting this on the model. did you happen to read the docs...?  - https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Answer (score 9):

If you want to give a default value without two-way binding, use `[value]`:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="input01">UUID</label>
  <input id="input01" type="text" [value]="beacon.uuid" class="form-control form-control-rounded" name="uuid" disabled>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="input01">UUID</label>
    <input class="form-control form-control-rounded" id="input01" style="width:600px;margin-left:60px" type="text" [(ngModel)]="beacon.uuid" name="uuid" [disabled]="true">
  </div>
```

In your component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  beacon.uuid = "my default value"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the value from input

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="input01">UUID</label>
    <input class="form-control form-control-rounded" id="input01" type="text" [(ngModel)]="beacon.uuid" name="uuid" disabled>
</div>
```

Otherwise it will be a conflict between your style and disabled attribute